# Maven dependency scope test not added transitively

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a module in which I added the dependency of cassandra-unit with scope test.

This module I am adding as a dependency in another project, but it is not adding cassandra-unit to the build path. Why?  Is it something to do with scope test? Will setting optional as false help, i think by-default it is true.

Answer (score 2):

Because dependencies in the test scope are not transitive.

In general in maven there is a "claim" that the dependencies are transitive, but its not true all all the scopes that maven supports.

Check out [this schema](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) to see which rules of transitivity apply to which scopes